# Issues installing drivers for an alfa wifi adapter

Tags: drivers, kernel, compiling, make

I've recently bought a ALFA AWUS036NH adapter it works fine on windows but on my ubuntu OS seems to not work i've found that I needed to install rtl8187l driver so it can work but it keeps returning errors here's the log:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-46-generic' arch/x86/Makefile:156: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
Makefile:975: "Cannot use CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel"
  CC [M]  /home/user/Downloads/rtl8187-Linux-Driver-master/rtl8187/r8187_core.o
/bin/sh: 1: gcc: not found
scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target '/home/user/Downloads/rtl8187-Linux-Driver-master/rtl8187/r8187_core.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/user/Downloads/rtl8187-Linux-Driver-master/rtl8187/r8187_core.o] Error 127
Makefile:1551: recipe for target '_module_/home/user/Downloads/rtl8187-Linux-Driver-master/rtl8187' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/user/Downloads/rtl8187-Linux-Driver-master/rtl8187] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-46-generic'
Makefile:14: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

lsusb:

```
us 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub<br>
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1a2c:4c5e China Resource Semico Co., Ltd<br>
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 18f8:0f99 [Maxxter] Optical gaming mouse<br>
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 148f:3070 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070 Wireless Adapter<br>
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I also have installed linux headers and build-essential.

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lsusb` and please do `sudo apt install build-essential`

Comment: I already had it installed i forgot to mention it.

Comment: You should already have a module in the kernel, rt2800usb.  It isn't going to help a Ralink wifi by installing a realtek module

Comment: I'm not sure is there a way to check it? the network adapter doesn't seem to work

Comment: Post URL from terminal for `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && chmod +x wireless-info && ./wireless-info && cat wireless-info.txt | nc termbin.com 9999`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/A3NiMHCF

Comment: Anything with `sudo ifconfig wlan1 up`

Comment: I've already tried it also I tried turning off the pci wifi adapter(wlan0) and enabling the wlan1 but still no result

Comment: What Ubuntu OS is this?

Comment: I fixed it by unplugging the usb adapter and plugging it in an another usb port it works now not sure what happened here.